# ASP Authentication : Unable to validate data error in read and decrypt data from cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, cookies, encryption

I make single sign in but it has error,I know the machine key in all web config is the same and authentication is the same too. but it just work in sub domains not in main domain. in global.ascx my website can not decrypt the cookies and cant authenticate the user and show this error : Unable to validate data.
this is my machine key:

```
<machineKey alidationKey="C50B3C8..96DB51F17C529AD3CABE" decryptionKey="8A9BE8FD67A...F2B72F" validation="SHA1"/>
```

**Note:** accounts.domain.com and eticket.domain.com are working but domain.com dose not work and show this error.
these are my codes in global and FormsAuthentication.Decrypt has this error:

```
 protected void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
{
    if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported == true)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
        {
            try
            {
                //let us take out the username now                
                string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;

                //let us extract the roles from our own custom cookie
                string roles = Class1
                    .GetUserRoles(username);

                //Let us set the Pricipal with our user specific details
                e.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(username, "Forms"), roles.Split(';'));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //somehting went wrong
            }


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us your `<authentication>` node from `web.config`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is solved by this code add to `<machinekey>` : `compatibilityMode="Framework45"`